# Python add a variable to a class

Tags: python

I am trying to understand python classes:

I have the following case:

```
class parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
    def printFoo(self):
        print(self.a)
        
        
class child(parent):
    def createC(self, val): # Create a variable inside the derived class?
        self.c = val
    
    def printFoo(self): # overloaded function
        print(self.c)
        
a = parent()
b = child()

b.createC(3)
b.printFoo()
# Edited:
# I can even create variables as: child.d = 10
```

I would like to define a variable `c` and store it in the `child` class. Is it suitable to do this? Should I define an `__init__` method to create the variable?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can/should definitely have `__init__` in the derived classes. You just need to initialize the base class via `super` method. Here is the example according to your case.

```py
class parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
    def printFoo(self):
        print(self.a)
        
        
class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # initialize base class, pass any parameters to base here if it requires any
        self.c = someval
    # def createC(self, val): dont need these
    #    self.c = val
    
    def printFoo(self): # overloaded function
        print(self.c)
```

If your base class requires some parameters, you can do it like this

```py
class parent:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def printFoo(self):
        print(self.a)
        
        
class child(parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b, someval):
        super().__init__(a, b) # initialize base class, pass any parameters to base here if it requires any
        self.c = someval
    #def createC(self, val): dont need these
    #    self.c = val
    
    def printFoo(self): # overloaded function
        print(self.c)
```

Comment: Hi thanks, 

I just noticed that I can even add  variables from outside the class. 
something like `child.c = 30`.

Comment: Funnily I thought you had to call `super().__init__()` to initialise the base class, but I just tried the example code above and `self.a` and `self.b` were initialised correctly, in python 3.8.8.

Comment: @JohnM. try my 2nd example without `super().__init__()` and you'll know.

Comment: @ThomasJerry yes you can do it, but you should not do it like this as it is not a good practice.

Comment: It's clear the second example needs initialisation, but if the base constructor has no input parameters it seems to work OK. I think there is a strong best practice argument.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your variable to change ? You can simply put `c` inside your new child class, such as a static class variable (have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-and-methods-in-python?rq=1) maybe).

```
class child(parent):
    c = 3
```

You can access it doing :

```
child.c
```

If you want to pass by the `__init__()` function and define the new variable when you define the class, use the `super()` method as [@Ahmad Anis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10342778/ahmad-anis) was suggested.